# Can't assign image in .xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode

I was using xcode 6.0. A day before, I updated to xCode 6.1.1, and now I can't assign images to .xcassets by drag and drop.

Usually I would just drag and drop images into the 1x, 2x boxes. But now when I try to do so the boxes just disappear!

Here is what happens..

[image]

Once I drag the unassigned image to the box,

[image]

It just disappears, leaving the assets unassigned!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work around for this. Creating a copy of the same asset and deleting it's contents and then reassigning the same image somehow works.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that in my case that didn't work either..

Finally I had to settle with accessing files directly by name.

```
[UIImage imageNamed: @"xxxxx.png"]
```